# Elasticsearch painless returns wrong long values

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Elasticsearch returns the rounded value when I try to get millis from the timestamp (using docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.11.0 image).

My mappings:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
         ...
            "updated_at": {
                "type": "date"
            }
         ...
        }
    }
}
```

My script query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "script": {
                "source": "doc['updated_at'].value.millis"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
{
    ...
    "hits": {
        ...
        "max_score": 1616185130000,
        "hits": [
            {
                ...
                "_score": 1616185130000,    <---- wrong value
                "_source": {
                    ...
                    "updated_at": 1616185148409    <---- should be this
                }
            },
            {
                ...
                "_score": 1616185130000,    <---- same wrong value even if updated_at is different
                "_source": {
                    ...
                    "updated_at": 1616185148408    <---- should be this
                }
            }
            ...
```

Also tried with long type in mappings:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
         ...
            "updated_at": {
                "type": "long"
            }
         ...
        }
    }
}
```

Query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "script_score": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "script": {
                "source": "doc['updated_at'].value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And got the same results.

I can't use sorting because we need boost by formula and I stuck with this issue.

Comment: Can you show the `updated_at` value that you have in your `_source` document?

Comment: @Val They are present in the results: 1616185148408, 1616185148409

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you index those exact values, and not a date string, right?

Comment: @Val Yes you are right, I put the number in the index

Comment: Found solution: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11872

Comment: Yes, if you multiply your score by some factor that will bring the long value into the accepted float spectrum, then it would work.

Comment: @Val thanks for help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because the `_score` of each document is of [type `float`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/509a1549540f1f4664ded036623c1d12cf536947/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/SearchHit.java#L74).

A `long` value in Java has 64 bits precision while a `float` has 32 bits precision, so trying to fit a long into a float will make you lose some precision.

Try this:

```
long test = 1616185148409L;
System.out.println("Value as long: " + value);
System.out.println("Value as float: " + (float)value);
```

Results:

```
Value as long: 1616185148409
Value as float: 1.61618513E12
```

Which is consistent with what you're seeing.